# Remove PDF page breaks

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ghostscript

How can I remove page breaks from a pdf, so the output would be a single 'page' PDF? So if a normal page is 400x900 and I have 4 pages, a resulting file would be 1600x900. I previously did this for Tif files ([Remove page breaks in multi-page tif to make one long page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313594/remove-page-breaks-in-multi-page-tif-to-make-one-long-page)), but would like to do it with PDF. Could I possibly convert to ps, remove whatever code means 'page break', then convert back to pdf?

Comment: Do you want annotations to also be present on the merged page? If not, @Colton's answer shows the way. Improvement is possible, though, e.g. joining pages with different dimensions is not done properly, and some optimizations concerning the required resources are possible, too.

Comment: Quite right. I have updated my example to deal with pages of varying dimensions (both in width and height). Added using statement for better memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in the iTextSharp library by using a single columned PdfTable and dynamically changing the size of the document dependent upon the number of pages.

You'll of course need a few references to the iTextSharp DLL found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
```

Here's a simple example:

```
public static void MergePages()
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\cmilne\Desktop\AA0081913.pdf"))//Original PDF containing page breaks. 
    {
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        float postProcessPageHeight = 0;
        float postProcessPageWidth = 0;
        for (int p = 1; p <= bill.PageCount; p++)
        {
            var size = bill.PdfReader.GetPageSize(p);
            postProcessPageHeight += (size.Height);
            if (size.Width > postProcessPageWidth)
                postProcessPageWidth = (size.Width);
        }

        var rect = new Rectangle(postProcessPageWidth, postProcessPageHeight);

        using (Document document = new Document(rect, 0, 0, 0, 0)) 
        { 
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\cmilne\Desktop\AA0081913_NEW.pdf", FileMode.Create)); //Declare location\name of new PDF not containing page breaks.

            document.Open();
            PdfImportedPage page;
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.WidthPercentage = 100;

            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                table.AddCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
            }
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The ending page size must be smaller than 14400 by 14400. (This is all that iTextSharp allows) An 8 1/2 x 11 PDF at a common resolution would make the max about 18 pages.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I missed OPs comment until today!

Comment: I have updated my example to deal with pages of varying dimensions (both in width and height). Added using statement for better memory usage.

Comment: The code works BUT it didn't solve the problem. It just made the 1st page bigger and there were still two pages. Ugh. Downvote

Answer (score 1):

Use the iTextSharp C# library.  It gives you a lot of options to manipulate PDFs.  I've used it before when I had to write an import application for a closed-source document repository.  It worked like a charm.  The only downside is their documentation is kind of spotty because they want you to purchase their book.  You can browser their Java API though for free since its almost identical to the C#, and just play around with it to find the C# version.

iText: http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: iTextSharp certainly does have a lot of options for manipulating PDFs, but I'm not seeing the option to remove page breaks. Do you know if it has that option?